# c# How to show the csv data in datagridview(windows tool) when button2 is clicked?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, datagridview, buttonclick

How to show the csv data in `datagridview`(windows tool) when button2 is clicked?

```
public class CsvImport
{
        public static DataTable NewDataTable(string fileName, string delimiters, bool firstRowContainsFieldNames = true)
        {
            DataTable result = new DataTable();

            using (TextFieldParser tfp = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
            {
                tfp.SetDelimiters(delimiters);

                // Get Some Column Names
                if (!tfp.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fields = tfp.ReadFields();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        if (firstRowContainsFieldNames)
                            result.Columns.Add(fields[i]);
                        else
                            result.Columns.Add("Col" + i);
                    }

                    // If first line is data then add it
                    if (!firstRowContainsFieldNames)
                        result.Rows.Add(fields);
                }

                // Get Remaining Rows
                while (!tfp.EndOfData)
                    result.Rows.Add(tfp.ReadFields());
            }

            return result;

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datagridview1. result;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the datatable containing the output data as an itemssource for the datagrid.
The answer would be datagridview1.ItemsSource=result.You can just call the function returning the datatable result.

Comment: I add "datagridview1.ItemsSource=result; into the button2_Click, but it shows red line under datagridview1 and result which mean it does not exist in this context. How to solve?

Comment: Check the id of the datagrid which you are using in the designer.